# string.split vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a text in database which is "computer-hardware". I used that code to split

```
            ' string seperated by colons '-'
            Dim info As String = strcotegory

            Dim arInfo As String() = New String(3) {}

            ' define which character is seperating fields
            Dim splitter As Char() = {"-"c}

            arInfo = info.Split(splitter)

            For x As Integer = 0 To arInfo.Length - 1
                Response.Write(arInfo(x) & "</br>  ")
            Next
```

but now I want to get "computer" in textbox1 and "hardware" in textbox2.

please guide me

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you correctly, replace the `For` loop with the following lines of code:

```
textbox1.Text = arInfo(0)
textbox2.Text = arInfo(1)
```

---

By the way, initializing `arInfo` (`... = New String(3) {}`) is not necessary, since you overwrite the value of `arInfo` anyway (`arInfo = ...`).